# When is $\det(AA^T) \neq \det(A^TA)?$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, determinant

Given that $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ and $\det(A^T)=\det(A)$ then why is it not always the case that:

> $\det(A^TA)=\det(AA^T)$
>
> $\det(A^T)\det(A)=\det(A)\det(A^T)$
>
> $\det(A)\det(A)=\det(A)\det(A)$
>
> $(\det(A))^2=(\det(A))^2$    **for any matrix A?**

Comment: What if $A$ is not a square matrix? Your argument works for square matrices

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes I thought so but which one of those statements are only for square matrices?

Comment: $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ is only true of $A,B$ are square. $AA^T$ and $A^TA$ are always square, even when $A$ isn’t.

Comment: In particular, when $A$ isn’t square, $\det(A)$ is not defined.

Comment: In the non-square case it will generally be false. Consider the case when $A$ is $m\times n$, $m<n$. Then $\det(A^T A)=0$ since $\operatorname{rank}(A^T A)\le \operatorname{rank}(A)\le m$. However, $AA^T$ could still be full rank, and hence have non-zero determinant.

Comment: By the matrix determinant lemma, at least the following is true: $\det(I_N +AB) = \det(I_M+BA)$ for any $A,B$.